# Anamorphic lens flare effect to text using only CSS

Tags: css

I know it's possible to get an overall 'neon' like effect to text using text-shadows, but is it possible to give text the more asymmetric, 'horizontal' type flare as seen in movies, usually referred to as anamorphic lens flares?  (see example).[image: anamorphic lens flare example]

EDIT:

Here is an example http://dabblet.com/gist/11479993

The text here shows four levels of text-shadows using blur to approximate a symmetrical 'glow' around it.  Is there a way to only increase this effect on the right and left sides only, so that there is a horizontal-like glow effect that converges into an imaginary horizontal axis that running through the middle of the text.

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.float {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 1px 150px #FFF, 2px 0 60px #FFF, 2px 0 5px #FFF;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='text'>s</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any text in your example ...

Comment: Not as a native function like text-shadow.  You'll have to use an image, but the big question is... do you need it to move?

Comment: you can do a bunch of circles with gradients http://neilmagee.com/demo/css3-lens-flares/

Comment: Or a bunch of radial gradients

Comment: added text and example, thanks.

Comment: the problem with adding a bunch of circles of gradients is that the effect is then symmetric, as in a circle.  What I'm looking for is to increase the flare effect along the horizontal axis only.

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially create one o more ellipses in CSS.

You would need to add gradients as colors as to simulate your effect.

Here just a brief example:

http://jsfiddle.net/w2rcy270/2/

```
#effect {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    background: rgb(240, 183, 161);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1) 48%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1)), color-stop(48%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1) 48%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1) 48%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1) 48%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(240, 183, 161, 1) 0%, rgba(140, 51, 16, 1) 48%, rgba(191, 110, 78, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f0b7a1', endColorstr='#bf6e4e', GradientType=1);
}
```